# Jump script in unity involving rb.velocity not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code and inspector data, I am rookie in unity And I do not have an idea why it is not working. I tagged this as a 3D problem, since I think it wouldn't work in either. I watched some youtube videos and other posts, and I cannot find a mistake.I would be grateful for any help.

[This is picture of my inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok5LV.jpg)

```
public Animator animator;
public SpriteRenderer sprite;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 playerDirection;
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
public float fallMultiplier=2.5f;
public float lowJumpMultiplier=2f;

void Update()
{ 
    playerDirection.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    
    //Animation
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (playerDirection.x != 0)
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);
    else
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //flip
    ////////////////////////
    if (playerDirection.x < 0)
    { 
        sprite.flipX = true;
    }
    if (playerDirection.x>0)
    {
        sprite.flipX = false;
    }
    ////////////////////////
    
    //Jump
    ///////////////////////
    
    ////////////////////////       
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + speed *playerDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
    if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * fallMultiplier * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    else
    if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - rb.gravityScale) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand the difference between Update and FixedUpdate. Update runs at all the frames. FixedUpdate runs at specific time intervals. What you are doing is registering user input in the FixedUpdate. That means that, you need to be lucky and have the FixedUpdate run at the specific frame you pressed the button. If you had pysics calculations, you should indeed place them in the FixedUpdate. However, when jumping, you do not, you simply set the velocity. Now, the falling part is interesting, because you do want that in the FixedUpdate.

Try this:

```
void Update()
{ 
    playerDirection.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    
    //Animation
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (playerDirection.x != 0)
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);
    else
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //flip
    ////////////////////////
    if (playerDirection.x < 0)
    { 
        sprite.flipX = true;
    }
    if (playerDirection.x>0)
    {
        sprite.flipX = false;
    }
    ////////////////////////
    
    //Jump
    ///////////////////////
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Jumping button registered");
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
    ////////////////////////       
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + speed *playerDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * fallMultiplier * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    else
    if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - rb.gravityScale) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Once you make sure that the jump is registered, it should probably work fine. If however you do NOT get console log when pressing the jump button, you should check your input settings.

Comment: First of all, thanks for clearing some things up for me, but it still does not fix the problem, jump button is assigned well, but the player isn't jumping for some reason, even If I rump up the jump force to a higher number.

Comment: Hmmmmm, there are quite a lot of things that could go wrong then... For example, if the axes are pointing in the wrong direction for some reason, the character will move in deapth instead of up and down. And on a 2d environment, you cannot see the difference. You can check that by watching your game in 3d in the scene view instead of the game one and also at the transform component. If that is not the case, try disabling the falling part and see what happens. Maybe there is some flaw in the logic there that we are both missing.

Comment: Okay, so all things you mentioned were good, so I decided to delete everything and just leave the jump script part open, and it worked! I guess the problem might be here
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + speed *playerDirection * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
where my playerDirection. y =0

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I just checked it, and it was the problem, I cant use .velocity and .moveposition together, atleast I dont know how, do you have any solutions?